# Digital Ocean Kubernetes one load balancer for two different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, nginx-ingress

I have an small kubernetes (3 small nodes) on Digital Ocean. I already configured production an it is working, but for development purposes I want to create a second environment (staging).

I have been working on and almost everything is working, but I can't get the network to work.

For example, I own the domain `example.com`

production will run on `www.example.com` and `api.example.com`. Then I have staging on a different kubernetes namespace `staging-www.example.com` and `staging-api.example.com`.

The only thing that this two environments are sharing are the load balancer. The issue I am facing is I cant go to `staging-www.example.com` and `staging-api.example.com`. I misconfigured something, I am trying to reach where is the misconfiguration

These two files are the ones I have for staging / ingress / network. As I wrote, for production is working, but there is something wrong for staging and I couldn't get where is the problem

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.digitalocean.com/load-balancer-id: "8ce613ac-a217-4537-b6ce-d26b0eef0939"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname: "example.com"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: staging
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - staging-www.example.com
    - staging-api.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: examplecatalogo-svc
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: staging-www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: examplecatalogo-svc
            port: 
              number: 80

  - host: staging-api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: examplenodeapi-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Comment: try removing this annotation : `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname`

Comment: @HarshManvar thanks for the comment. It seems that it didn't work, but I didn't realize that while I was setting up staging I broke production, I will need to get more information and update the question.

Comment: there is less chances you broke or stop production however i have faced similar issue if backed controller pod restarting or so